# How python code is interpreted and how much static analysis is there?

Tags: python

I thought python is a interpreted language but as per below code snip, it apparently is not doing exactly what I expect? I did some search on that, and it turns out python will 'declare' a name as local implicitly if there is an assignment for it within the function. So it does do some static analysis while interpreting the code, but my question is by how much?  e.g. as below code shown, wont it also optimise as x=1 is not reachable? do we have more details about how we interpret the code? thanks

```
x = 10
def f():
    if False: x = 1
    print x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2):

In CPython, the code is first compiled into *bytecodes*, and the bytecodes are then executed by the interpreter. Thus some problems (syntax errors etc) are caught before any code is executed.

If you wish, you can examine the bytecodes using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (False)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)

  4     >>   15 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             18 PRINT_ITEM          
             19 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, this particular CPython doesn't do a lot of optimization when translating Python to bytecodes.

Comment: ah, thats very useful tool :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no "static analysis" here, at least not as that's usually interpreted. There's just compilation.

When you reach the end of a `def` block, the compiler is called on the body to turn it into a `code` object, pretty much the same way the compiler is called on a line entered at the REPL.

It doesn't care that the assignment happens inside an `if` statement that can never happen. It still compiles the code inside that `if` block. And therefore, it's compiling an assignment to `x`. Part of compiling the `def` block is creating the `locals` dictionary, and when it compiles that assignment, it knows `x` is a local variable rather than a global, and that's all it needs.

Comment: The compiler does all it's work before any of the code in a module is executed, so it makes no sense to talk about the compiler doing anything 'when you reach the end of a def block'. What happens when you reach a `def` is that a function object is created from the code object that was created when the module was compiled.